# Attribute selected inside while

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a script that get all ids from a table and print them on option select form, and i want to reload page with the id i chose as selected on option. This is the script:

```
<?php
include('include/menu.php');
include('include/mysql.php');
if ($db_found) {
echo "<form action='' name='form' method ='get'>
<select name='funcionario'>";
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
$idfunc = $_GET['funcionario'];
$selected = ($idfunc==$idfunc->$db_field['idfunc']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                echo "<option value'".$db_field['idfunc']."' ".$select." onclick='document.form.submit();' >".$db_field['nomefunc']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</selected></form>";
        echo $idfunc;
} else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}
?>
```

But the script are always returning only the first id as selected.

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: see you defined `$selected` and you echoed `$select`

Comment: `$idfunc` is string, not a class object. How do you call `$idfunc->$db_field['idfunc']` out from it when you gave it a value `$idfunc = $_GET['functionario']`? I wonder how you didn't get php error here.

Comment: You cannot choose another option using `onclick`. It should be `onchange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$idfunc->` from `$idfunc->$db_field['idfunc']`

Replace `value'".$db_field['idfunc']."'` with `value='".$db_field['idfunc']."'`

You already defined `$idfunc = $_GET['functionario']` which is a string, not an class object.

Also you defined `$selected` but you are using `$select` when echoing the result.

For further debugging, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. I guess that's why you didn't get error when you tried to execute this script.

Here's complete script:

```
<?php
include('include/menu.php');
include('include/mysql.php');
if ($db_found) {
echo "<form action='' name='form' method ='get'>
<select name='funcionario'>";
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
          $idfunc = $_GET['funcionario'];
          $selected = ($idfunc==$db_field['idfunc']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
          echo "<option value='".$db_field['idfunc']."' $selected onclick='document.form.submit();'>".$db_field['nomefunc']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</selected></form>";
        echo $idfunc;
} else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}
?>
```

Comment: I get the error, my <option>CONTENT</option> are getting the CONTENT as value.

Comment: Worked as that

    $select = ($idfunc==$db_field['idfunc']) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option value='".$db_field['idfunc']."'  ".$select." onclick='submit();' >".$db_field['idfunc']." -  ".$db_field['nomefunc']."</option>";

now it's getting the value and printing $select on the right $idfunc only.
Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = ($idfunc)==$db_field['idfunc'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
  echo "<option value'".$db_field['idfunc']."' ".$selected." onclick='document.form.submit();' >".$db_field['nomefunc']."</option>";
```

I hope this is you want! Try this!